# How do I deploy Capistrano on a server with Rbenv when development environment is using RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, rvm, capistrano, rbenv

Bundle won't install upon Capistrano deploy. Everything else with the `cap deploy` is working fine.

The production environment is Ubuntu Debian 16.04 running Rbenv. The development environment is using RVM.

I was wondering if there was a way to set the cap deploy rules to iron out this inconsistency.

```
** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:


 DEBUG [97b85698] Finished in 1.117 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).

  INFO [b7136ad5] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /var/www/nginx-test/shared/public/assets /var/www/nginx-test/releases/20190429163546/public/assets as nginx-test@nginx-test.lailo.link

 DEBUG [b7136ad5] Command: /usr/bin/env ln -s /var/www/nginx-test/shared/public/assets /var/www/nginx-test/releases/20190429163546/public/assets

  INFO [34b3841f] Finished in 1.755 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

 DEBUG [9b69e352] Running if test ! -d /var/www/nginx-test/releases/20190429163546; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/nginx-test/releases/20190429163546'" 1>&2; false; fi as nginx-test@nginx-test.lailo.link

 DEBUG [9b69e352] Command: if test ! -d /var/www/nginx-test/releases/20190429163546; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/nginx-test/releases/20190429163546'" 1>&2; false; fi

 DEBUG [069154db] Finished in 2.145 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

 DEBUG [e726e46b] Running /usr/bin/env bundle check --path /var/www/nginx-test/shared/bundle as nginx-test@nginx-test.lailo.link

 DEBUG [e726e46b] Command: cd /var/www/nginx-test/releases/20190429163546 && /usr/bin/env bundle check --path /var/www/nginx-test/shared/bundle

 DEBUG [9392525f]   /usr/bin/env: 

 DEBUG [9392525f]   ‘bundle’

 DEBUG [9392525f]   : No such file or directory

 DEBUG [9392525f]   

 DEBUG [9392525f] Finished in 1.847 seconds with exit status 127 (failed).

  INFO [2bf3b442] Running /usr/bin/env bundle install --path /var/www/nginx-test/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --quiet as nginx-test@nginx-test.lailo.link

 DEBUG [2bf3b442] Command: cd /var/www/nginx-test/releases/20190429163546 && /usr/bin/env bundle install --path /var/www/nginx-test/shared/bundle --jobs 4 --without development test --deployment --quiet

 DEBUG [8b1a6d45]   /usr/bin/env: 

 DEBUG [8b1a6d45]   ‘bundle’

 DEBUG [8b1a6d45]   : No such file or directory

 DEBUG [8b1a6d45]
```

Comment: Is bundler installed on the host?

Comment: Yes it is.
Actually I fixed the problem, I just altered the path to the Ubuntu user's $PATH in the cap deploy.rb file:

```set :default_env, { path: "/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims:$PATH" }```

Posting here helped clear my mind though!